# Is it possible to have functions in base class, but lambda functions in sub class?

Tags: typescript

I'm using a third party api that has a d.ts definitions where a class have functions declared like so:

```
export class Bar {
    foo(): void;
}
```

now when I create an implementation of a sub class I want to use lambda function syntax

```
    export class Test1 extends Bar {
         public foo = (): void => {
              //DO Stuff
         }
    }
```

This does not compile because

> "Class 'Test1' defines instance member property 'foo', but extended
>   class 'Bar' defines it as instance member function."

Do I need to change the definition of the Bar-class for it to work with lambda-functions? I'd rather not, so if there is some other solution I'd appreciate the help!

**Update**

Ok, so i noticed something. If I instead of `extends` use `implements`, I'm allowed to use lamdba functions in Test1. To me it sounds weird to implement a class. The Bar-class does sort of look like a interface, could it be because of that it works?

Comment: Implements simply allows *you* to ensure type compatability and does no codegen (e.g. a call to the `__extends` function)

Answer (score 3):

If you use `implements`, you won't actually inherit from the base class - so if that base class had other properties and methods that you were hoping to access you would find them all absent from you `Test1` class.

When using `implements` you would have to implement all properties and methods specified in the structure.

Here is the transpiled JavaScript:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
        this.foo = function () {
        };
    }
    return Foo;
})();
```

If you use `extends` the compiler will emit additional code that extends your `Test1` class with the methods and properties of the base class.

When using `extends` you can optionally override methods, but do not have to implement all members as you inherit them from the base class.

Here is the transpiled JavaScript (you can see the additional code):

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var Foo = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Foo, _super);
    function Foo() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Foo.prototype.foo = function () {
    };
    return Foo;
})(Bar);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I think I will use implements since the base class does not actually have any implementation and I only want the type compatability.

Comment: But do you have any explanation regarding why I am allowed to use lambda style functions when using implements, but not when I extend?

Comment: That is a rule in the TypeScript compiler. You could argue that the rule should be changed, but it prevents some subtle problems you would run into if you inherited from your sub-class (you cannot override properties on a base class, only methods).